# 2002 Sub Forester S 2.5 AT Huge power loss going up hills

Tags: fuel-system, subaru, pressure

Can anyone tell me what the fuel pressure should be (40lbs ?) on a 2.5 AT Sub Forester. Any hill I hit the power drops to nothing and the cruise control shuts off (which I understand, it is suppose to)  Also does the fuel pump come out in a door beneath passenger side rear seat?

Comment: Is this just on hills? Can you go WOT on a flat road? Do you have a scan tool that can read live data or a data logging device?

Comment: pretty much just on hills.  don't know about log device maybe scan tool.  find out later today

Answer (score 1):

Any engine codes being shown? Any misfire issues?

There are many reasons why a Forester can lose power - MAF sensor, crankshaft position sensors, air leaks, knock sensor, EGR valves, throttle position sensors, etc; what in particular is making you zero in on the fuel pump? I'd suggest looking at the MAF first - it's easier to get to, and if it just needs a cleaning, a $6 can of MAF cleaner is in most budgets. If it needs replacing, it's a few hundred, but junk yards will have them.

The fuel pump is accessed via an oval hole in the floor - the right rear of the luggage compartment, so just behind the passenger side rear seat. Fuel pressure should be 33-40psi, measured just after the fuel filter in the engine compartment.

Comment: Removing the mass air flow sensor and cleaning tomorrow. Did not know this could cause the problem.  Will get back to you

Comment: Just remember that you don't touch the actual sensor in the housing - just squirt it with the cleaner... if you touch it, you'll probably damage it.

Comment: @ForesterDave IIRC that year engine doesn't use a MAF.

Comment: @Ben is correct! I pulled up the wrong FSM. It uses a MAP sensor - which I'd recommend grabbing from a junk yard.